# What causes this Page Not Found error in my Codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **[blog application](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog)** in **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4.

I have added a **registration and login** system to this application. I am current working on a password reset system.

In the **Changepasword** controller, the `index` method takes the parameters `$email` and `$token`:

```
public function index($email, $token) {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['tagline'] = 'New password';
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();

    // Form validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if(!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('auth/newpassword');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        $this->Usermodel->set_new_password($email, $token);
    }
}
```

In the routes file I have this line for the above controller:

```
$route['changepasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'changepasword/$1/$2/';
```

The entire routes file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'posts';
$route['install'] = 'install';
$route['migrate'] = 'migrate';
$route['register'] = 'register';
$route['login'] = 'login';
$route['newpassword'] = 'newpassword';
$route['changepasword'] = 'changepasword';
$route['changepasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'changepasword/$1/$2/';
$route['dashboard'] = 'dashboard';
$route['dashboard/create-post'] = 'dashboard/posts/create';
$route['dashboard/create-page'] = 'dashboard/pages/create';
$route['dashboard/create-category'] = 'dashboard/categories/create';
$route['dashboard/manage-authors'] = 'dashboard/users';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['categories/posts/(:any)'] = 'categories/posts/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'posts/post/$1';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I also added this to the `config.php` file:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@=&\-!';
```

Yet, at the URL `http://ciblog.com/changepasword/myaddress@gmail.com/f450469ac1970b06074acb7c430d431d` instead of the view being rendered, I get the error:

```
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.
```

If I use `md5($this->user_email)` instead of `$this->user_email` I get the URL: `http://ciblog.com/changepasword/ec9814883d7f7149bc15f1ed1f472da9/d7571dc4e25ea76278bee5eb45251f11`, but still, the **404 Page Not Found** erroe message.

All the code I have written so far for this update password functionality is **[HERE](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog/tree/password_reset_system)**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ sign is invalid in an URL. I think the **token** is enough to identify the user.

Comment: @AdamP. I added this to the config: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@=&\-!';`.

Comment: This trick not working, because this is a security rule in browsers it is not Codeigniter related.

Comment: @AdamP. The same happens if I md5 the email and get an URL like `http://mysite.co.uk/changepasword/ec9814883d7f7149bc15f1ed1f472da9/08c981bc4f279a485b210c9b7d6741bf`

Comment: Your repo is not up-to-date (last commit: 6 days ago). Please update repo and I check the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these 2 lines!

```
$route['changepasword'] = 'changepasword';
$route['changepasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'changepasword/$1/$2/';
```

**UPDATE:**
You forget to define function/method name in route:
Modify from this: `$route['newpasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'newpasword/$1/$2/';` to this: `$route['newpasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'newpasword/index/$1/$2/';` And the previous line (`$route['newpasword'] = 'newpasword';`) is deletable because you not use index  function without parameters.

Comment: With what shall I change them?

Comment: Change the order of these lines